# How to use zero shutter lag in Android Camera API 2?

Tags: android, android-camera2

As in title. How to make ZSL still picture with Camera 2 API? Should I only use `TEMPLATE_ZERO_SHUTTER_LAG`? Should I also add CONTROL_ENABLE_ZSL in `CaptureRequest`? Should I do precapture sequence before taking still? Currently I do not have any particular code, just thinking how do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is IMHO good example of using Camera 2 API by *Android Open Source Project*:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Camera2/+/9c94ab3/src/com/android/camera/one/v2/OneCameraZslImpl.java

It uses `TEMPLATE_ZERO_SHUTTER_LAG` but does not use `CONTROL_ENABLE_ZSL`.

Comment: it looks like, sollution in this class is software-based. And I think that it may be available hardware-level sollution when I set `CONTROL_ENABLE_ZSL`. I'm still searching...